# How to simplify xml request and response structure in .net web service

Tags: xml, web-services, web, request, response

I want to simplify my web service request and response xml structure:

At present :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetAddressForPostcode xmlns="http://dw.rhp.org.uk/StatementsService">
      <postcode>string</postcode>
      <addressline1>string</addressline1>
      <SearchType>string</SearchType>
    </GetAddressForPostcode>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

I WANT :

```
<GetAddressAuthorisation>
  <MethodParameters>
    <Postcode>SW14 7RD<Postcode>
 </MethodParameters>
</GetAddressAuthorisation>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want a SOAP or RESTful service? You will need the soap envelope and body in the first case. And why do you want to simplify it anyway? As long as you don't want to write a service client from scratch (and why would you do that)?

Comment: Is it possible to simplify it ? Can we achieve this result by any tool ?